# @SequenceGenerator not generating sequence

Tags: oracle12c, hibernate-5.x, sequence-generators

Whatever I am gonna say is very strange and very true, Please don't give negative marking.

Hibernet-core : 5.2.14
Spring -boot 2.0
DB : Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

This should create a sequence by the name INSUREDACCESSORYID_SEQ in DB but it fails to do so when I start my server.

```
private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="insuredAccessoryId_seq") 
    @SequenceGenerator(name="insuredAccessoryId_seq",sequenceName="INSUREDACCESSORYID_SEQ",allocationSize=1) Long id;
```

**Strange Thing:** If I change ( ADD / REMOVE ) a single/multiple alphabets 
in value of property **sequenceName=**   it will create a sequence. Changing a value of property will create a sequence.

Example :
 INSUREDACCESSORYID_SEQ         -->>         not work
 **J**INSUREDACCESSORYID_SEQ    -->>         Will create a sequence

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error with a name that *doesn*t work*? If so, which one?

Comment: No Error. Tables get created. Log is clean.